# iOS: Finding the NSArray of an item to delete from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, restkit

I'm implementing "swipe to delete" to a TableView with notifications from API. I created a method that deletes a notification when I hard-code its notification id (which is an array). The problem is I can't figure out how to get the exact notification id to delete.

There are TableView Delegate and TableView Data Source methods that somehow get the notification id, so I suppose I should be able to get it for the purpose of my method, but I've run out of ideas.

Here's my API source code:

```
  desc 'delete notifications'
  params do
    requires :notification_ids, type: Array
  end
  delete 'notifications/remove', root: :notifications, each_serializer:      NotificationSerializer do
    require_authentication!
    NotificationLogic.delete_notifications params[:notification_ids], current_user
    current_user.notifications
  end
```

Here's the method for deleting notifications:

```
-(void)deleteNotificationWithId:(NSArray*)ids withCompletionHandler:(DeleteNotificationCompletionHandler)handler
{
    NSDictionary* params = @{ @"notification_ids" : ids };

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
ReadNotificationRequest* req = [ReadNotificationRequest new];
req.notificationIds = ids;

[_objectManager deleteObject:nil
                     path:@"user/notifications/remove"
               parameters:params
                  success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                      _secondTry = NO;
                      NSArray* arr = mappingResult.array;
                      [self notififyAboutNotifications:arr];
                      handler(YES, arr, nil);
                  } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                      if (operation.HTTPRequestOperation.response.statusCode == 401 && !_secondTry)
                      {
                          [weakSelf relogin:^{
                              [weakSelf deleteNotificationWithId:ids withCompletionHandler:handler];
                          }];
                          return;
                      }
                      handler(NO, nil, error);
                  }];
}
```

and implementation of the method in NotificationTableView. It works, but I hard-code the array with number:

```
-(void)setNotifications:(NSMutableArray *)notifications{
_notifications = notifications;
[self reloadData];
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    //Remove item in array
    [self.notifications removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Also remove that row from the table view with an animation
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    //Remove hard-coded notification from server
    [[Api sharedInstance]deleteNotificationWithId:@[@756]
                            withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL succes, Message *response, NSError *error) {
                                if(succes){

                                } else {
                                    [Utils alert:error.pop_message];
                                }
                            }];}
}

#pragma mark TableView Data Source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return self.notifications.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NotificationTableViewCell* cell = [self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NotificationTableViewCell"];
[cell configureCellWithNotification:self.notifications[indexPath.row]];

return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
Notification* not = self.notifications[indexPath.row];
[self.notificationDelegate notificationTapped:not];
}
```

Comment: Cant u just get the ID from your data array with the indexpath u got in your delete row method when the user swipe to delete, then send it in background thread to your server (1 ID = 1 request), if multiple ID with 1 request u should create a button to confirm the deletion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code

```
//Remove item in array
[self.notifications removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Deletes the information you need, just before you need it. Instead of deleting it, read the ID out first, then delete it and use the ID.

Comment: you're right! I put this pieace of code later and I was able to read the ID